# Why I can't change or swipe tab on my TabLayout in Android?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-tablayout

[image]

I want to make a screen like the picture above. so if I select a tab in the TabLayout, then it will change some variable before making request to server and eventually the data from server will populate the recycler view.

I use `addOnTabSelectedListener` on TabLayout to retrieve the change If the user change the tab. usually in some tutorials, they always use tab layout with some fragment change, so it seems they use viewPager to handle it. but in this case I remove it and I just use `addOnTabSelectedListener` to get the change, and because I just need one recycler view instead of more than one fragments

here is the code I use in my fragment

```
class SearchResultFragment : Fragment() {

    lateinit var fragmentView : View
    lateinit var recyclerView : RecyclerView
    lateinit var tabLayout : TabLayout

    lateinit var mContext : Context
    lateinit var mActivity : FragmentActivity

    private var selectedEventType = EventType.kajianUmum
    private var selectedCity = City.defaultCityName
    private var selectedTime = "Akhir Pekan"

    lateinit var eventAdapter : GeneralEventRecyclerViewAdapter
    private var  eventList = ArrayList<Event>()

    override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
        super.onAttach(context)

        mContext = context
        activity?.let { mActivity = it }

    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        fragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_search_result, container, false)

        setUpSafeArg()
        setUpViewsDeclaration()
        setUpListeners()

        initRecyclerView()


        return fragmentView
    }

    private fun setUpViewsDeclaration() {
        recyclerView = fragmentView.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView_event_general_search_result)
        tabLayout = fragmentView.findViewById(R.id.tabLayout_time_search_result)

    }

    private fun setUpSafeArg() {
        arguments?.let {

            val args = SearchResultFragmentArgs.fromBundle(it)
            selectedEventType = args.selectedEventType
            selectedCity = args.selectedCity
            selectedTime = args.selectedTime

        }
    }

    private fun setUpListeners() {

        tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(object: TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener {

            override fun onTabSelected(tab: TabLayout.Tab?) {

                when(tab?.position ?: 0) {
                    0 -> mActivity.toast("0")
                    1 ->  mActivity.toast("1")
                    2 ->  mActivity.toast("2")
                    3 ->  mActivity.toast("3")
                    4 ->  mActivity.toast("0")
                    else -> println("Number too high")
                }

            }

            override fun onTabReselected(tab: TabLayout.Tab?) {

            }

            override fun onTabUnselected(tab: TabLayout.Tab?) {

            }


        })

    }




    private fun initRecyclerView() {

        eventAdapter = GeneralEventRecyclerViewAdapter(mContext)
        val layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(mContext, RecyclerView.VERTICAL,false)
        recyclerView.adapter = eventAdapter
        recyclerView.layoutManager = layoutManager

        eventAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(object: OnEventKMListener {

            override fun eventKMClicked(position: Int) {
                val selectedEvent = eventList[position]
                val eventDetailDestination = SearchResultFragmentDirections.actionGlobalDestinationEventDetail(selectedEvent)
                Navigation.findNavController(fragmentView).navigate(eventDetailDestination)
            }

        })

    }

}
```

but I don't know why I can't change the tab when I run the app, I also can't swipe that tab. the tab is stay on index 0

here is my xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                                                   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                                                   android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                                   android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                                   tools:context=".Fragments.Search.SearchResultFragment" android:id="@+id/constraintLayout_search_result">


    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" android:layout_marginEnd="16dp" android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" android:id="@+id/tabLayout_time_search_result">

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Hari Ini"/>

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Besok"/>

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Akhir Pekan"/>

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Pekan Depan"/>

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Semua"/>

    </com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout>

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:layout_width="379dp"
            android:layout_height="635dp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tabLayout_time_search_result"
            android:id="@+id/recyclerView_event_general_search_result"
            tools:listitem="@layout/item_general_event"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

and here is my MainActivity:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), NavController.OnDestinationChangedListener {

    private lateinit var navController : NavController
    lateinit var destinationTitleTextView : TextView
    lateinit var progressBar : ProgressBar
    lateinit var topToolbar : Toolbar
    lateinit var bottomNavigationView : BottomNavigationView


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this)

        // Initial Setup views
        navController = Navigation.findNavController(this,R.id.nav_host_fragment)
        setupBottomNavMenu(navController)
        setupActionBar(navController)
        setUpViewDeclaration()


        // Add Listeners
        navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener(this)


    }



    override fun dispatchTouchEvent(event: MotionEvent): Boolean {

        // to hide softkeyboard when tapping outside area in the fragment
        // And in the layout of the fragment use this attribute: android:focusableInTouchMode="true"

        if (event.action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            val v = currentFocus
            if (v is EditText) {
                val outRect = Rect()
                v.getGlobalVisibleRect(outRect)
                if (!outRect.contains(event.rawX.toInt(), event.rawY.toInt())) {
                    v.clearFocus()
                    val imm = getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
                    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(v.windowToken, 0)
                }
            }
        }
        return super.dispatchTouchEvent(event)
    }



    private fun setUpViewDeclaration() {
        destinationTitleTextView = findViewById(R.id.destination_label_text_view)
        progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progressBar_main_activity)
        topToolbar = findViewById(R.id.top_toolbar)
        bottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.bottom_nav)

    }

    private fun setupBottomNavMenu(navController: NavController) {
        bottom_nav.setupWithNavController(navController)
    }


    private fun setupActionBar(navController: NavController) {

        setSupportActionBar(top_toolbar)
        supportActionBar?.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false)

        // set up top hierarchy destination
        val appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(setOf(
            R.id.destination_home,
            R.id.destination_search,
            R.id.destination_user_control,
            R.id.destination_create_event)
        )

        top_toolbar.setupWithNavController(navController,appBarConfiguration)

    }

    override fun onDestinationChanged(controller: NavController, destination: NavDestination, arguments: Bundle?) {

        progressBar.visibility = View.GONE // to ensure progress bar will be gone whenever the user segues to other destination




        // set toolbar and bottom navigation visibility
        if (destination.id == R.id.destination_welcome ||
            destination.id == R.id.destination_authentication ||
            destination.id == R.id.destination_loginUsingEmail ||
            destination.id == R.id.destination_registerUsingEmail ||
            destination.id == R.id.destination_choose_user_location ||
            destination.id == R.id.destination_change_password ||
            destination.id == R.id.destination_create_event_finished_info ||
            destination.id == R.id.destination_photo_view

        ) {

            topToolbar.visibility = View.GONE
            bottomNavigationView.visibility = View.GONE

        } else if (

            destination.id == R.id.destination_create_event_name ||
            destination.id == R.id.destination_create_event_type ||
            destination.id == R.id.destination_create_event_starting_date ||
            destination.id == R.id.destination_create_event_ending_date ||
            destination.id == R.id.destination_create_event_speaker ||
            destination.id == R.id.destination_create_event_description ||
            destination.id == R.id.destination_create_event_poster ||
            destination.id == R.id.destination_create_event_coordinate ||
            destination.id == R.id.destination_create_event_location_detail ||
            destination.id == R.id.destination_create_event_contact ||
            destination.id == R.id.destination_create_event_price ||
            destination.id == R.id.destination_create_event_capacity ||
            destination.id == R.id.destination_create_event_summary ||
            destination.id == R.id.destination_create_event_finished_info ||
            destination.id == R.id.destination_event_detail ||
            destination.id == R.id.destination_event_description_detail ||
            destination.id == R.id.destination_map_detail_location

        ) {

            topToolbar.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            bottomNavigationView.visibility = View.GONE

        } else if (
            destination.id == R.id.destination_user_control ||
            destination.id == R.id.destination_search

        ) {

            topToolbar.visibility = View.GONE
            bottomNavigationView.visibility = View.VISIBLE

        } else {

            topToolbar.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            bottomNavigationView.visibility = View.VISIBLE

        }







        // Set Toolbar Title
        if (destination.id == R.id.destination_home) {
            destinationTitleTextView.setText(R.string.home)
        } else if (destination.id == R.id.destination_create_event_summary) {
            destinationTitleTextView.text = "Ringkasan"
        } else if (
            destination.id == R.id.destination_create_event ||
            destination.id == R.id.destination_create_event_name ||
            destination.id == R.id.destination_create_event_type ||
            destination.id == R.id.destination_create_event_starting_date ||
            destination.id == R.id.destination_create_event_ending_date ||
            destination.id == R.id.destination_create_event_speaker ||
            destination.id == R.id.destination_create_event_description ||
            destination.id == R.id.destination_create_event_poster ||
            destination.id == R.id.destination_create_event_coordinate ||
            destination.id == R.id.destination_create_event_location_detail ||
            destination.id == R.id.destination_create_event_contact ||
            destination.id == R.id.destination_create_event_capacity ||
            destination.id == R.id.destination_create_event_price ||
            destination.id == R.id.destination_create_event_summary ||
            destination.id == R.id.destination_create_event_finished_info

        ) {

            destinationTitleTextView.setText(R.string.createEvent)

        } else {

            destinationTitleTextView.text = ""

        }




    }


}
```

what went wrong in here ?
java is ok

Comment: You cannot swipe if you don't use `ViewPager`.
Will it toasting when you click on each tab?

Comment: @AdmiralKunkka no.

Comment: Can you post your MainActivity?

Comment: @JohnJoe I have added my main activity. I am using Single Activity on my entire app since I use navigation controller component

Answer (score 2):

You can use TabHost to make this thing though it is an old way. And another way is wrapping viewpager in a tablayout. Here is some good tutorial for this.

1. TabHost: https://www.dev2qa.com/android-tabhost-example/
2. ViewPager:https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-swipe-view

Comment: I little bit confused if use viewPager, I have watched tutorial to make this like in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QU5-IpnEub4. I am confused because it seems that I have to make 3 fragments if I have 3 tabs. but in my case, I don't need it, because I only  have one recycler view. so I have to make other 3 fragments ?

Comment: I'm not sure actually how to make tabs with recycler view.